# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, nft, solana-wallet-adapter

I was working on this repository to breed NFTs on Solana. However, I encountered an error while attempting to mint a new generation. The first two test cases, "Initialize" and "Compute," have passed successfully. The new generation has been generated during the "Compute" phase, as indicated by the transaction showing "generation: true" from 0 to 1. However, during the minting process, I encountered the following error:

"Do you happen to know what the problem is? Has anyone else faced a similar issue?"

repo link: https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding

Comment: what was the error!

Comment: @Jimii
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's attempting to use program ID `NFTBfAcFhBb8yqNvYiN8RPQfr5KrVuHGK7pj61EiVnZ`, which when searched does not appear as a valid program address on Mainnet and Devnet. If it's any different, let me know. But from the repo link, the program appears to be attempting to use that program ID which does not exist.

Comment: I deploy the contract, change the programID, and run the test cases then, it shows this error.
@hunter

Comment: @UmaidKhalid are you changing the program ID here for `NFT_BREEDING_PROGRAM_ID` as well? 

https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding/blob/5d4f26bec2037ba0bb097056ed132d75ab1ba3df/ts/ids.ts#L4

Comment: Yes, I was changes in 3 files., Anchor.toml, lib.rs and ids file.
But issues still faced.
@hunt actually 2 test cases run as well as generation has been create but issue come on before minting the nft.